# How to randomize the text size of each word in ConTeXT?

Tags: fontsize, context, context-mkiv

Beginning with a passage of text like this:

```
This is a sample passage.
```

How can I set each word to randomly appear at a different size, from a list of 3-4 possible sizes?

E.g., in the output, "This" might be big, "is" might be small, "a" might be medium size, etc.

- Each time the document is rendered, they can be different sizes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Besides the two commands mentioned by Aditya and Henri ConTeXt also provides the commands `\applytosplitstringwordspaced` and `\applytosplitstringcharspaced` to apply a command to each `word` or `character` in the given argument.

```
\startluacode

function userdata.randomwordsize(str)
    local sizes = { "10pt", "12pt", "14pt", "16pt", "18pt", "20pt" }
    local size  = sizes[math.random(1,6)]
    context.startfont{ string.formatters["Serif at %s"](size) }
        context(str)
    context.stopfont()
end

\stopluacode

\starttext

\defineexpandable[1]\RandomWordSize
  {\ctxlua{userdata.randomwordsize("#1")}}

\applytosplitstringwordspaced\RandomWordSize
  {The fraction of fossil olfactory receptor genes is significantly
   higher in all species with full color vision. This suggests that
   the evolution of trichromatic vision --- which allows these
   primates to detect food, mates, and danger with visual cues ---
   has reduced their reliance on the sense of smell.}

\blank

\applytosplitstringcharspaced\RandomWordSize
  {The fraction of fossil olfactory receptor genes is significantly
   higher in all species with full color vision. This suggests that
   the evolution of trichromatic vision --- which allows these
   primates to detect food, mates, and danger with visual cues ---
   has reduced their reliance on the sense of smell.}

\stoptext
```

[image: Random size for each word in a string]

Answer (score 4):

The hard part is to isolate words from a passage, and apply an arbitrary macro to each of the words. ConTeXt provides a command `\processwords` that does this. To use this command, you first have to define a macro `\processword` that will act on a particular word.

As an example, suppose you want to draw a frame around each word. Then, define:

```
\def\processword{\inframed}

\starttext
Normal text \processwords{This is a simple passage.} Normal text
\stoptext
```

which gives

[image]

Now, the next step is to create a macro that picks a random font size and applies that.

Answer (score 3):

Aditya's answer is in principle correct but the naïve macro to randomize the font size will not work.  This is because by default `\processwords` uses the [“old call”](https://github.com/contextgarden/context-mirror/blob/5794d8b0c845aad2ab4cf36dc14201b21ef5a784/tex/context/base/mkiv/supp-box.mkiv#L1421-L1426) where each word is put in a box and the `\processword` macro is only evaluated once.  To mitigate this, we have to manually switch to the [“MetaFun call”](https://github.com/contextgarden/context-mirror/blob/5794d8b0c845aad2ab4cf36dc14201b21ef5a784/tex/context/base/mkiv/syst-aux.mkiv#L7848-L7859) which also does not need to call to Lua.

```
\def\processword#1{{\switchtobodyfont[\randomnumber{5}{15}pt]#1}}

\starttext

Normal text \processwords{This is a simple passage.} Normal text

\unprotect
\def\processwords#1%
  {\syst_helpers_process_word#1 \_e_o_w_}% no \unskip
\protect
Normal text \processwords{This is a simple passage.}Normal text

\stoptext
```

[image]

Alternatively you can use `\processseparatedlist` which allows you to use an arbitrary separator:

```
\processseparatedlist
  [This is a simple passage.]
  [ ]
  {\groupedcommand{\bgroup\switchtobodyfont[\randomnumber{5}{15}pt]}{\space\egroup}}
```

In all cases, look out for spurious spaces after the list.